# Webpack-dev-server proxy requests very slow

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I am using webpack-dev-server proxy:

```
devServer: {
        proxy: {
            '/api': {
                target: 'http://mybackedn.url',
                changeOrigin: true
            }
        }
    }
```

Requests take too much time.
Chrome network panel shows this: [image]

Why this happens? How to solve this problem?

Comment: Have you resolved the issue somehow, please? i have similar problem

Comment: have you make a configuration on your DNS? it needs some time and then it works again efficiently

Comment: Maybe related to this issue : https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/161 (though I am not sure why bounty such an old question, since I doubt OP will answer any question on their problem)

Comment: Is the grapic a filtered list of network activity? If so it looks consistent with standard queuing for more than 6 connections from a single source.

Comment: can you attach the screenshot hovering the waterfall graphs that you marked in the above screen shot

Comment: Thank you @Selbor! Would be better to put it as answer indicating the source too

Answer (score 5):

The grey part in the request time graph is called stalled-time and the light-grey part(after grey) is queuing time. You can see the same if hover on the waterfall graphs. Here is whats causing issue and what stalled time means.

> #### Stalled/Blocking
>
> Time the request spent waiting before it could be sent. This time is inclusive of any time spent in proxy negotiation. Additionally, this time will include when the browser is waiting for an already established connection to become available for re-use, obeying Chrome's [maximum six](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=12066) TCP connection per origin rule.

(If you forget, Chrome has an "Explanation" link in the hover tooltip and under the "Timing" panel.)

Basically, the primary reason you will see this is because Chrome will only download 6 files per-server at a time and other requests will be stalled until a connection slot becomes available.

This isn't necessarily something that needs fixing, but one way to avoid the stalled state would be to distribute the files across multiple domain names and/or servers, keeping [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) in mind if applicable to your needs, however HTTP2 is probably a better option going forward. Resource bundling (like JS and CSS concatenation) can also help to reduce amount of stalled connections.

**Alternatively** you can de-priotise the requests and triggeer then at the end that are taking long time so that rest of the requests wont wait for the slow runners.

Answer (score 4):

I was facing similar issues where every proxied request took 5 seconds or more  with a setup something like this:

```
"proxy": [
    {
      "context": [
        "/api",
      ],
      "target": "http://my-backend-server.local:1234",
      "secure": false
    }
  ]
```

And in the hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1    my-backend-server.local
127.0.0.1    some-other-hostname.local
127.0.0.1    a-few-more-of-these.local
```

When I changed the proxy to point to the IPv6 loopback address the problem went away. So like this:

```
"proxy": [
    {
      "context": [
        "/api",
      ],
      "target": "http://[::1]:1234",
      "secure": false
    }
  ]
```

To be able to use the actual hostname in the proxy configuration instead of the loopback address, I edited my hosts file to contain all hostname entries on a single line and point them to both IPv4 and IPv6 loopback addresses. So like this:

```
127.0.0.1    my-backend-server.local some-other-hostname.local a-few-more-of-these.local
::1          my-backend-server.local some-other-hostname.local a-few-more-of-these.local
```

Now the latency is gone and it works as expected.

Comment: This issue cropped up for me today (~4 years after initial post) and this solution of `::1` somehow worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
devServer: {
   proxy: {
      '/api': {
        target: 'http://mybackedn.url',
        changeOrigin: true,
        headers: {
          Connection: 'keep-alive' // add this can fix this issue
        }
      }
   }
}
```